# Bound on $\|RR^T\|$ for random matrix $R$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

Let $R$ be a $n \times k$ matrix ($n<k$) where each entry of $R$ is drawn independently from $N(0,1)$. I wanted to know, what is a bound, possibly probabilistic, on $\| RR^T\|$? Any pointers or references would be appreciated.

Comment: You might have a look, e.g., [here](http://math.mit.edu/~edelman/thesis/thesis.pdf). For the rest, $\|RR^T\|_2=\|R\|_2^2$. The thesis actually refers with one result which might interest you (page 64) to another paper, but I have not found that one.